# Using gitversion with gitflow and github actions for nuget package

Tags: github, nuget, github-actions, git-flow, gitversion

We use gitflow and gitversion for versioning. I am trying to come up with a workflow for releasing nuget package using github actions to push packages whenever a feature is merged to develop (alpha suffix, pre-release nuget package), release branch is created from develop (beta suffix, pre-release nuget package) or release branch is merged to main (no suffix, Release nuget package). Can anyone help me with the pipeline ? So far I was able to get to a point where the develop packages are released without any issue. problem comes when I create a release branch. The workflow is not triggered. Here is the pipeline I'm using:

``
name: Build and Publish NuGet Package
on:
push:
branches:
- '*'

jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
        fetch-depth: 0

  - name: Setup .NET
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
    with:
      dotnet-version: 7.0.x

  - name: Install GitVersion
    run: dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool

  - name: Configure GitVersion
    run: dotnet-gitversion /config /.github/GitVersion.yml  

  - name: Configure NuGet Feed
    run: dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name UltimateSuite "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ultimatesuite/index.json  "

  - name: Restore dependencies
    run: dotnet restore

  - name: Build and Pack
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release
        && dotnet pack --configuration Release --no-build --output ./nuget

  - name: Archive NuGet package
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: nuget-package
      path: ./nuget
```

```
  publish:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/release/') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download NuGet package
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: nuget-package
          path: ./nuget

      - name: Publish NuGet package 
        run: dotnet nuget push ./nuget/*.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/*******/index.json   --api-key ${{ github.token }}

``


Thanks!
```